# How to use process to run several commands

Tags: c#, process, exit-code

I have a process , use it to run several commands.

```
Process mycmd = new Process();

    mycmd.StartInfo = startInfo1;
    mycmd.Start();
    if (mycmd.ExitCode > 0)
    {
    // do something
    }
    mycmd.StartInfo = startInfo2;
    mycmd.Start();
    if (mycmd.ExitCode > 0)
    {
    // do something else
    }
```

First time the command is executed the exitcode is 1. It is saved for the second run also. How can I reset the exit code?
Other question is - is it ok to call to "start" twice?

Comment: I believe you may want to start a new process instead of a new set of start info on the same process.

Comment: Agreeing with @ZackCampbell, it seems like a design flaw to allow `Start` to be called twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call `Start()` on the `Process` instance, a new process is created and system allocates resources for it. Such resources are process handle and other attributes like exit code and exit time. If you write something like:

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
var exitCode = p.ExitCode;
Console.WriteLine("Handle: {0}, PID: {1}, Exit code: {2}", p.Handle.ToInt32(), p.Id, exitCode);

p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
exitCode = p.ExitCode;
Console.WriteLine("Handle: {0}, PID: {1}, Exit code: {2}", p.Handle.ToInt32(), p.Id, exitCode);
```

and make both processes return different values (by typing in command windows e.g. *exit 1* and *exit 2* respectively), you'll get the output similar to this one:

```
Handle: 1308, PID: 9060, Exit code: 1
Handle: 1324, PID: 8428, Exit code: 2
```

Process properties like `ExitCode` and `Handle` properly return values for the last terminated process. But they are lost for the process run previously and you also have a *resource leak* because system resources allocated for the previous process have not been disposed (the following quote is from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> If a handle is open to the process, the operating system releases the
>   process memory when the process has exited, but retains administrative
>   information about the process, such as the handle, exit code, and exit
>   time. To get this information, you can use the ExitCode and ExitTime
>   properties. These properties are populated automatically for processes
>   that were started by this component. The administrative information is
>   released when all the Process components that are associated with the
>   system process are destroyed and hold no more handles to the exited
>   process.

`Process` type implements `IDisposable` interface and these components are destroyed when you call `Close()` (or `Dispose()`) on the `Process` instance (the following quote is from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.close(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> The Close method causes the process to stop waiting for exit if it was
>   waiting, closes the process handle, and clears process-specific
>   properties. (...) The Dispose method calls Close. Placing the Process
>   object in a using block disposes of resources without the need to call
>   Close.

The proper way of using `Process` to run two processes would include calling `Dispose()`:

```
using (var p = new Process())
{
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    var exitCode = p.ExitCode;
    Console.WriteLine("Handle: {0}, PID: {1}, Exit code: {2}", p.Handle.ToInt32(), p.Id, exitCode);
}

using (var p = new Process())
{
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    var exitCode = p.ExitCode;
    Console.WriteLine("Handle: {0}, PID: {1}, Exit code: {2}", p.Handle.ToInt32(), p.Id, exitCode);
}
```